# I want to create new table using login user data from a form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following code and I want to use `Forms!Login!cboUser` as `NewTableName`:

```
If DLookup("[AccessLevelID]", "Users", "[UserID] = " & Forms!Login!cboUser) = 1 Then

    Dim dbs As Database

    Set dbs = OpenDatabase("C:\Users\Yiannis\Desktop\photo list - Copy")

    dbs.Execute "CREATE TABLE [NewTableName] " _
    & "([Item No] TEXT, Quantity NUMBER);"

End If
```

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: What would happen if the table already exists?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
If DLookup("[AccessLevelID]", "Users", "[UserID] = " & Forms!Login!cboUser) = 1 Then

    Dim dbs As Database

    Set dbs = OpenDatabase("C:\Users\Yiannis\Desktop\photo list - Copy")

    dbs.Execute "CREATE TABLE [" & Forms!Login!cboUser.Column(n) & "] " _
    & "([Item No] TEXT, Quantity NUMBER);"

End If
```

where you set *n* to the column of the combobox that holds the username.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct code. It works great. Thanks a lot